# Exception not be caught by class and visual studio 2019 stopping at "Exception Unhandled"

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to create a class with a method to handle all exceptions.  It accepts a pointer to a function, executes that function and then will handle if the function throws an exception.  I then created a function get an invalid substring to prove the exception is caught, however, my class isn't getting the exception and Visual Studio is breaking on the substring line saying "Exception Unhandled"

cpp file:

```
#include "TestHarness.h"

using namespace TestHarness;

int testFunc();

int main()
{
    Tester myTest;

    std::cout << myTest.execute(testFunc);

    return 0;
}

int testFunc()
{
    std::cout << "My Test Func" << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::string("abc").substr(10);

    return 6;
}
```

h file:

```
#define TESTHARNESS_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

namespace TestHarness
{

    class Tester
    {
    public:
        int execute(int(*func)());
    private:
        bool result;
    };

    int Tester::execute(int(*func)())
    {
        try {
            (*func)();
            result = true;
            return 1;
        }
        catch (const std::runtime_error& e)
        {
            std::cout << e.what();
            result = false;
            return 0;
        }

    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: For divide by zero, that answer makes sense.  However, I tried doing something else with a substring to throw an exception and it still isn't going to the class.

Comment: @NathanOliver You might be thinking of UB translating into SEH exceptions *sometimes*, but `substr` is [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to throw on out-of-range invocation.

Comment: @Quentin Please check the edit history.  The OP originally had a division by zero example.

Comment: @NathanOliver indeed. OP, don't be afraid of opening new questions even if you think they are similar (in this case they weren't). SO is not well-suited to evolving issues or discussion but rather to individual, clear-cut Q&As.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, really: `substr` throws `std::out_of_range`, which does [not](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range) derive from `std::runtime_error` but from `std::logic_error`, itself derived from `std::exception`. Just catch `std::exception const &` or `std::logic_error const &`. Here is a [list of inheritance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) for all standard exception types.